# POWER BI Rest API Authentication using PHP

Tags: php, powerbi

I am trying to authenticate using REST APIs, on my PHP backend. However, I am unable to obtain the auth code or access token.
 I've registered my application on https://dev.powerbi.com/apps as a server side web-app, and have selected "Read and Write Datasets" permission on the 
This is my code :

```
$url = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize"."?response_type=code"."&client_id=<my_client_id>"."&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"."&redirect_uri=<my_redirect_url>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$head = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I run this code, literally nothing happens. It doesn't redirect to my redirect URI.